# Changing tk.label text from function within class

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Getting the error "AttributeError: 'MainPage' object has no attribute 'deftext1'". Am I not defining 'deftext1' when I initially create it?

I should add that I am a beginner, so apologies if something (or all of it) looks a mess.

```
 import tkinter as tk

 class example(tk.Tk):

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

         tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

         tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Example")
         tk.Tk.wm_geometry(self, '800x600')

         container = tk.Frame(self)
         container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

         container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
         container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

         self.frames = {}

         frame = MainPage(container, self)
         self.frames[MainPage] = frame
         frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

         self.show_frame(MainPage)

     def show_frame(self, cont):

         frame = self.frames[cont]
         frame.tkraise()

 class MainPage(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
         tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

         deftext1 = tk.Label(self, text="Text to change", font=("Arial Bold", 20))
         deftext1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

         button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Load",
                     command=lambda: self.updateLists())
         button1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

     def updateLists(self):
         self.deftext1.config(text='It Worked')

 app=example() app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are missing the `self` keyword. needs to be `self.deftext1 = tk.Label(...)`

Comment: @FrainBr33z3 How would I make the same text change from outside the class? I was experimenting but getting similar error messages again.

Comment: @champinoman ***"from outside the class"***: You need the instance reference to `class MainPage`. E.g. `<ref to MainPage>.deftext1`

Comment: @stovfl I tried using `MainPage.updateLists(MainPage)` but get the error "ttributeError: type object 'MainPage' has no attribute 'deftext1'" again.

Comment: ***"tried using `MainPage.updateLists(MainPage)`"***: You didn't get the difference between `class Definition` and `class Instance`. `MainPage` is the name of a `class Definition`. Here, `frame = MainPage(container, self)`, `frame = ...` get assigned the **instance reference of the class MainPage**. Use: `app.frames[MainPage].updateLists()`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `deftext1` is a local variable, it is not the attribute of the class

Edit `deftext1` to `self.deftext1` so that it becomes an attribute of the class.

**Your Code:**

```py
import tkinter as tk

 class example(tk.Tk):

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

         tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

         tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Example")
         tk.Tk.wm_geometry(self, '800x600')

         container = tk.Frame(self)
         container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

         container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
         container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

         self.frames = {}

         frame = MainPage(container, self)
         self.frames[MainPage] = frame
         frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

         self.show_frame(MainPage)

     def show_frame(self, cont):

         frame = self.frames[cont]
         frame.tkraise()

 class MainPage(tk.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
         tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

         self.deftext1 = tk.Label(self, text="Text to change", font=("Arial Bold", 20))
         self.deftext1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

         button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Load",
                     command=lambda: self.updateLists())
         button1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

     def updateLists(self):
         self.deftext1.config(text='It Worked')

 app=example()
 app.mainloop()
```

I **HOPE** it worked.